# How to show product under category & home page slide show in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I have installed magento 1.9.2 on xampp. it working fine. But I have added an category under that category adding some product. After adding that product its not showing. I have installed minimalism_mag theme but this not working properly. So please help me

Answer (score 0):

Does the product show if you switch to the included themes (e.g, rwd)? If yes, then there is probably a problem with the minimalism_mag theme.

If no, then the product may not be fully configured to show on the front end. Check that the 'Status' and 'Visibility' settings are set appropriately. Also check the settings on the 'Inventory' tab.

Finally, make sure that you have re-indexed and cleared caches.

Comment: Sry but i am new for magento so please tell where should i change setting.

Comment: Please help me BonnevilleSlim.

Comment: Go to the product in the admin.

On the "General" tab, make sure that the "Status" field is set to "Enabled". Then set the "Visibility" field is set to "Catalog", "Search" or "Catalog, Search".

On the "Inventory" tab you have a couple options, but for testing you can set "Manage Inventory" to "No" (You may have to uncheck the "Use Config Settings" box directly below the field).

This should allow the product to be seen on the front end, e.g. by going to the corresponding category page.

Comment: You can also check here for a more complete answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6565/product-doesnt-appear-in-store-view-info-there-are-no-products-matching-the-s